# how to fix User Defined Function scalar value performance issue in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, t-sql

User Defined Function is used in stored procedure. The User Defined Function returns scalar value. Following logic used in the User Defined Function

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Test] ( @Code varchar(10),  )  
  RETURNS bit AS    
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @bFlag bit  

  SELECT @bFlag = COUNT(id)  
    FROM tbL1  
   WHERE Code = @Code  

  IF  @bFlag = 0   
  BEGIN  
    SELECT @bFlag = COUNT(id)  
      FROM tbl2
     WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Code)) = @Code  
  END  

  IF @bFlag = 0   
  BEGIN  
    SELECT @bFlag = COUNT(id)  
      FROM tbl3  
     WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Code)) = @Code  
  END  

  IF @bFlag = 0   
  BEGIN  
    SELECT @bFlag = COUNT(id)  
      FROM tbl4
     WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Code)) = @Code  
  END

RETURN @bFlag
```

which is correct way to improve performance in the above User Defined Function?

Comment: Since you're only returning an On/Off bit, you're only interested if there is one or more records that satisfy the condition?

Comment: It's a performance issue when misused. Like this.

Comment: This code is **horrible**. Assigning COUNT() to a bit, to everyone's overflowing delight. Doing a full count for simple existence check. Using space trimming to compensate for data impurity. Obvious bad data model if a value has to be searched across 4 tables. Is this some sort of bad codding contest finalist or something?

Answer (score 8):

The best way of improving performance would be to ditch the UDF entirely.

One immediate thing that occurs to me is that

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(Code)) = @Code
```

is not sargable so each call (i.e. **every row** returned in your outer query) could lead to up to 4 table scans.

If you replace the logic in the UDF with a CASE expression inline in the query you may well get a [much superior execution plan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx). Even if you can not make the predicate sargable at least it will allow the optimiser to explore different join strategies such as hash join rather than forcing repeated scans of the same tables.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands...

`WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Code)) = @Code;` the use of ltrim(rtrim(.. will prevent an index from being used.

Ideally you should have the result of `ltrim(rtrim(Code))` as an indexed col so that an index can be used in your WHERE clause. This will speed things up.

Setting `@bFlag = COUNT(id)` when `@bFlag` is an int and `COUNT(id)` an int is not so nice! You really ought to use a `CASE WHEN COUNT(id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` or otherwise.

However, it is more efficient to use the approach of `IF EXISTS` as this will short circuit as soon as a single row matching your criteria is found.

i.e.

```
DECLARE @bFlag bit 
SELECT @bFlag = 0

IF EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM tbl1 where Code= @Code ) SELECT @bFlag = 1
-- etc.
RETURN @bFlag
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Ah, didn't know such a thing existed. Thanks for pointing me to it.